# Wordpress exit the define Post?

Tags: wordpress

I create category image thumbnails, here i want to which post have no images the post is exit(); .Here is my code for found post image, but how can exit the particular post that have dont image. plz specify me.

```
       <?php //found the images from the post content
          global $post, $posts;
          $postContent = $post->post_content;
          $searchimages = '~<img [^>]* />~';

          preg_match_all( $searchimages, $postContent, $post_imgs );

          // Check to see if we have at least 1 image
          $findImages = count( $post_imgs[0] );

          if ( $findImages > 0 ) {
           echo "found"."<br />";

          } else {
            echo "not found"."<br />";
          }
        ?>
```

Here i define the not found, but i want to this not found post is exit;

Answer (score 0):

If by exit, you mean exiting out the braces (of an if/else statement), use a simple break; function.